# How to add formGroups dynamically to another fromGroup in Angular JS?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I need to create a dynamic form where the formGroup name is dynamic which comes from an array of retailerCategories. But I am getting error like below.  I have tried many ways but couldn't make it work

```
 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'commission -> retailerCategory -> Migration
```

Here's the array that comes as retailerCategories

```
"retailerCategories":[
         "Migration",
         "Platinum",
         "Gold",
         "Silver",
         "Bronze",
         "Category",
         "ABC",
         "v",
         "n"
      ]
```

In The Html what I have done is

```
<ng-container formGroupName="commission">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let category of retailerCategory; let i=index" formGroupName="retailerCategory" >
                            <ng-container  [formGroupName]="category">
                                <div class="commission-table-cell div-table-cell">
                                    <div >
                                        <fieldset [disabled]="isFieldDisabled('threshold')">
                                            <input class="commission-input" formControlName="threshold" type="number" oninput="allow2DecPlace(this)" onblur="fix2DecPlace(this)" step="0.01">
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="commission-table-cell div-table-cell">
                                    <div >
                                        <fieldset [disabled]="isFieldDisabled('amount')">
                                            <input class="commission-input" formControlName="amount" type="number" oninput="allow2DecPlace(this)" onblur="fix2DecPlace(this)" step="0.01">
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>


newSlab(count: number): FormGroup {
    let slab = 'SLAB-'.concat(count.toString())
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      slab: [slab],
      from: [''],
      to: [''],
      commission: this.formBuilder.group({
        threshold: [''],
        amount: [''],
        retailerCategory: this.getRetailerCategoryGroup()
      })
    })
  }



 getRetailerCategoryGroup(): FormGroup {
    let retailerCategoryGroup = {}
    for (let category of this.retailerCategories) {
      retailerCategoryGroup = Object.assign(this.formBuilder.group({
        category: this.formBuilder.group({
          threshold: [''],
          amount: ['']
        })
      }))
    }
    return new FormGroup(retailerCategoryGroup);
  }
```

I need the form json to be like this

```
{
      "slab": "slab-2",
      "from": 3,
      "to": 5,
      "commission": {
        "retailerCategory": {
          "Migration": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          },
          "Platinum": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          },
          "Gold": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          },
          "Silver": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          },
          "Bronze": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          },
          "Category": {
            "amount": 20,
            "threshold": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use FormArray to have dynamic form structure.
Check Angular Documentation:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Comment: I tried to make it work with formArray too but couldn't.